# JavaScript: how can I, on click, change the text of my item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning the JavaScript language and I'd like to reproduce something. I have a text called "Pause" and I'd like that, on click, another text replaces it with "Play".

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
(function($) {
    $('#slideshow-pause-icon').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#slideshow, #slider, figcaption, #timeline').toggleClass('slideshow-pause');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <span id="slideshow-pause-icon" title="Click to pause">Pause</span>
    <div id="slideshow-container">
        <div id="slider">
            <figure>
                <a href="style-1.php">
                    <img src="images/image-1.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>Style 1</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="style-2.php">
                    <img src="images/image-2.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>Style 2</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="style-3.php">
                    <img src="images/image-3.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>Style 3</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <a href="style-4.php">
                    <img src="images/image-4.jpg" alt="">
                    <figcaption>Style 4</figcaption>
                </a>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <span id="timeline"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, when I click on the "Pause" text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYg7h.png

the `slideshow-pause` class is displayed and it has this CSS:

```
.slideshow-pause
{
    animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused !important;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused !important;
}
```

Using JavaScript, I'd like that by clicking on the "Pause" text, my span ID `slideshow-pause-icon`is replaced by something like this:

```
<span id="slideshow-play-icon" title="Click to play">Play</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You really should be using an `anchor` tag rather than a span to do clicks. Additionally asking to replace the `span` with another element doesn't make sense, just use the same one. @void shows a good example, except he's missing the `#`

Comment: Yes, but I need to work with an ID or a class to style.

Comment: So just toggle the class when you switch the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(document).on("click", "#slideshow-pause-icon, #slideshow-play-icon", function(){

       $(this).html()=="Play"?$(this).html("Pause"):$(this).html("Play");
       this.id= (this.id=="slideshow-pause-icon"?"slideshow-play-icon":"slideshow-pause-icon");
       this.title = (this.title=="Click to pause"?"Click to play":"Click to pause");
       $("#slideshow, #slider, figcaption, #timeline").toggleClass("slideshow-pause");

    });
```

This is gonna work for you.

Comment: It works, but how can I, when I click on this item: http://prntscr.com/66qus1  a replacement to it? http://prntscr.com/66qv39

Comment: I dont actually got you? Do you want `<span id="slideshow-pause-icon" title="Click to pause">Pause</span>` to replace with  `<span id="slideshow-play-icon" title="Click to play">Play</span>`?

Comment: You can not have multiple id to a single element

Comment: I use IDs and not classes. It is possible to replace it?

Comment: This is perfect. Unfortunately, by putting your code, I lost the class which allowed me to stop the animation for these items: http://prntscr.com/66rk8f  How can I add your code without removing this?

Comment: Which class you want to add

Comment: When I click on "Pause", I'd like to add the class `slideshow-pause` to these items: `#slideshow, #slider, figcaption, #timeline`

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude. Thanks for your help. :) I can't vote up, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery is quite easy:

```
$("#slideshow-play-icon").text("Pause");
```

Comment: It wouldn't be `val` it's `text` instead since it's a span

Comment: I'd like that when clicking on my "Pause" span ID, it is replaced by a different span id (play), so another text.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  Just check if it has the class you're using to drive the text.  It looks like this is playing an image gallery?

```js
$('#slideshow-pause-icon').click(function()
{
 var $this = $(this);
 if($this.hasClass('slideshow-pause'))
 {
  $this.removeClass('slideshow-pause').text('Play');
                //do something else to play the image gallery
 }
 else
 {
  $this.addClass('slideshow-pause').text('Pause');
               //do something else to pause the image gallery
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <span id="slideshow-pause-icon" class='slideshow-pause' title="Click to pause">Pause</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, a slideshow. I still have a problem. I'd like to have something like this:  http://prntscr.com/66r9m3